# Creating Voronoi diagrams using JTS and the manhattan or minkowski distance metrics

Tags: distance, voronoi-thiessen, jts-topology-suite

In Java I am using the JTS library. Is it possible to use this library to generate Voronoi sites using different types of distance functions?

https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/triangulate/VoronoiDiagramBuilder.html

for example
*voronoi sites using Euclidean Distance:

[image: euclidean]

*voronoi sites using Manhattan Distance: **( what i want to do using JTS but dont know how )**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JTS Voronoi algorithm is designed to use only the Euclidean distance.  And given the compexity of the underlying code, I doubt it's feasible to generalize it to other distance metrics.